# Set skype avatar doesnt work in C# using Skype4Com

Tags: c#, skype, skype4com

I want to set my skype avatar using this C# code:

```
string path = "C:\\a.jpg";
string cmdstr = "SET AVATAR" + " " + "1" + " " + path;

Command cmd = new Command(0, cmdstr);
skype.SendCommand(cmd);
```

this code doesnt work, but if i use this code in VBA it works:

```
Public skype As New Skype
Dim cmdStr, path As String
path = "C:\a.jpg"
cmdStr = "SET AVATAR" + " " + "1" + " " + path
skype.SendCommand skype.Command(0, cmdStr)
```

It has something to do with the extension of the image or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a partial solution:

```
            string path = "C:\\b.jpg";
            var skype = new SKYPE4COMLib.Skype();
            var cmd = new SKYPE4COMLib.Command();
            cmd.Command = string.Format("SET AVATAR 1 {0}", path);              
            skype.SendCommand(cmd);
```

But the path only works if the image is stored in the root directory.